# How can I keep my windows, created by using pysimplegui, from going unresponsive?

Tags: python, oop, pysimplegui

I have a main window whose layout determines the functions of its buttons.
If the button "Parse" is clicked on, a thread is started in which my parse function is executed.
I am attempting to use a queue to determine the progress of the functions execution by
using the get method to update a variable which will be used to update the progress bar.

Due to the fact that I am using a while loop my windows go unresponsive.

The progress bar is a separate window from the main and I am having trouble figuring out a way to make this work. Most of the examples of threading are in OOP which I am not very good at yet.

```
elif event == "Parse":

        if layout == 1:
            
            q = queue.Queue()
        
            layout = [[GUI.Text('Parsing...')],
                      [GUI.ProgressBar(1, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progressbar', bar_color = ('navy','white'))]]
            window1 = GUI.Window('Progress', layout).Finalize()
            progress_bar = window1['progressbar']
            
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=ParseTSLogs, daemon=True, args = (q,))
            t1.start()

            temp = 0
            print(temp)
            while temp != 3:
                temp = q.get()
                progress_bar.UpdateBar(temp,3)

            window1.close()
```

How can I keep my windows from going unresponsive if I cannot put the progress window code inside of a queue? As I said I don't fully understand the many thread/queue examples as they are written in OOP.

Comment: What's the `q`  and what's the `ParseTSLogs` ?

Comment: Windowing applications need a running event loop. If you are in a tight loop waiting for temp to be set to 3 you are not processing events. Instead, when whatever `q.get()` is doing become 3 on the worker thread, use `event_generate` to post an event to your UI thread and bind a handler to that virtual event. You *must* allow mainloop to process events at all times.

Comment: There are a number of newer APIs in PySimpleGUI to help with "long operations" and lots of demo programs.  If you have not read the docs about them and looked at the calls, I'm sure it'll help to read them.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly... I believe I have a running event loop (while True). This elif statement is one of the events.  have added q. ParseTSLogs is a function that is used to parse logs. I understand why this won't work. I am having a hard time finding a fix for it...